# R: boxplots include -999 which were defined as NA -> dependent on order of factor declaration and NA declaration

Tags: r, boxplot, na

Situation:
.csv file which contains the following:

```
x,y,z
1,2,3
-999,2,4
2,-999,4
2,4,-999
```

following tasks:

1. format variables correctly (factors)
2. define "-999" as NA
3. calculate mean size > A
4. create some boxplots

Issue:
If I am using the function `replace_with_na_all` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/replace-with-na.html) the calculation of the mean size will throw me this error for the mean calculation:

> Argument is not numeric nor boolean: return NA

The boxplots look fine though.

If I am using the integrated NA declaration `df[df == -999] <- NA` the calculation of the mean values works well.
But the boxplot will show one graph including the "-999" only for the variable "x", if I first format the variables correctly as.factor and define the `NA`s afterwards.
Also the `summary(df)` command shows -999:0 for the variable `x`.

If I first define the `NA`s and convert to factor then everything is as supposed and I get plotted only the defined factors.
The `summary(df)` function will not show -999 for the variable.

These issues do not happen with other variables which I define as factors too.

Code sample:

```r
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/Jeremias/Desktop/test.csv")
df[df == -999] <- NA
f$x <- as.factor(df$x) 
mean(df[df$y > 1,"y"],na.rm = T)
boxplot(data = df, df$y ~ df$x, outline = F)
```

It took me several hours to find the solution (correct order), and I would like to understand the why.

Maybe some more experienced user has an explanation for this behaviour, if this is just R specific or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you already concluded correctly it depends on the (correct) order. As soon as you define **UrbanTrail$Geschlecht** as factor its levels will be saved as attribute of the variable, as can be shown:

```
UrbanTrail <- data.frame(Geschlecht = c(1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,-999), 
                         Wohungsgroesse = 61:70)

UrbanTrail$Geschlecht <- as.factor(UrbanTrail$Geschlecht)

attr(UrbanTrail$Geschlecht, "levels") # Attributes: levels "-999", "1", "2" 

UrbanTrail[UrbanTrail$Geschlecht == -999, "Geschlecht"] <- NA  # Even though "-999" becomes 'NA ...

attr(UrbanTrail$Geschlecht, "levels")                           # ... attributes remain the same: levels "-999", "1", "2"
```

After -999 becomes NA its levels are not adjusted accordingly.
If you make a boxplot, boxplot will look for the levels (just as we did in this example) and find "-999", "1" and "2" and will use these as categories, as the levels are not modified after -999 becomes NA.

Probably **replace_with_na** will automatically modify the levels of the variable afterwards.

Best regards from Leipzig

Chris

P.S.:

I can strongly recommend  reading "R for Data Science"
https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html